# Print characters before matching a pattern

Tags: awk, position, match, prefix

Following is a combination of awk commands

```
awk '
    {if ($0~/>/) {head=$0;getline}
    {if($0~/pattern/) print head"\n"$0}}' filename1 | 
awk 
   'BEGIN  {pos=0;char=0}
    {if($0~/>/) head=$0;getline}
    {pos=0; 
     if($0~/pattern/)
       {pos=match($0,/pattern/);char=substr($0,pos,55)} 
     print head"\n"char}'
```

Above one works great, I wanted to capture 55 characters after identifying the pattern "AATTGGCC". Problem is how can I get 55 characters prefix to a matching pattern (55 words before the matching pattern).
Yes,I can write the whole this in perl, but since I have the above in awk was wondering if I can modify it somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Working with genetic data, I presume?

Comment: To start, put the awk program into a separate file and properly format it.

This will help you to write and debug it, and it will allow you to post clean code in your question.

Comment: @Michael: The formatting was my fault; I'm not familiar with awk.  Feel free to edit.

Comment: It is awkward awk. Since you are writing it like Python code, not like awk at all, you really should take a look at Python.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit brute force but you could use a pattern that has 55 periods before AATTGGCC

For instance:

`/.......................................................AATTGGCC/ {print substr(%$0,1,55)}`

should do the trick. It would be better to see if awk regular expressions support subexpressions.

But the best would be to use Python and a [library like pygep](http://code.google.com/p/pygep/) because Python is used a lot in bioinformatics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of a way to print some characters that precede a pattern:

```
echo 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | 
    awk 'BEGIN {pat = "jkl"; n = 5} 
        pat {
            i = index($0,pat);
            print substr($0, i-n, n + length(pat))
        }'
```

Output (five character before "jkl" and "jkl"):

```
efghijkl
```

If your data has newlines and the character sequence you want to output spans across newlines, you'll need to accumulate the lines, remove the newlines and keep enough characters onhand in a buffer variable so you can output them.

For what it's worth, here is a simplified version of your script. It may not function correctly, but it's more readable and more AWKish. I haven't done anything to it to try to make it perform your required function nor have I tested it.

```
awk '

    />/ {head = $0; getline}

    /pattern/ print head "\n" $0

    ' filename1 | 
awk '

    BEGIN  {pos = 0; char = 0}

    />/) {head = $0; getline}
    {
        pos = 0; 
        if ($0 ~ /pattern/) {
            pos = match($0, /pattern/); char = substr($0, pos, 55)
        } 
        print head "\n" char
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having some sample input, it's hard to test, but I believe your  very C-like awk can be reduced to this:

```
awk -v pattern="abcd_or_whatever" -v n=55'
    />/ {head=$0; next}
    pos = match($0, pattern) {print head "\n" substr($0, pos, n)} 
'
```

and to get the 55 chars before the match, you just have to change the substr arguments to `substr($0, pos-n, n)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your suggestions. 
Regarding the format of the awk code, well I was not executing it in a proper script or anything. It was all in command line and hence so much of "piping" of the output. But I do understand and will try to write the codes in proper format whenever asking for help.

I found that RSTART in awk is a variable that keeps track of matching pattern, hence I was able to use it as follows (this is only part of the actual command).

```
awk 'BEGIN{pos=0;char=0}{if($0~/>/) head=$0;getline} {pos=0;if($0~/pattern/) {match($0,/pattern/);char=substr($0,RSTART-47,47)}print head"\n"char}'.
```

This goes back 47 chars back from the matching pattern and prints it.

Comment: Found one Caveat upon checking, if the position of the pattern is short then 47 (as I want a 55-mers=number of characters before the pattern+characters in the pattern(7)) the above still prints it. So to care of that need to have a statement like if pos> length(char), then print